# How to migrate to k8s kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I'm a begginer with k8s and I don't have knowlege about helm, kustomization, gitops, flux2 and other related terms.

I have an app on my k8s cluster and my goal is to move to Gitops using Flux2. Flux2 is forcing me to use kustomization so my current goal is to migrate my manifests to kustomization.

#### What I'm Trying To Do

Migrating the deployment and service manifests from my k8s cluster to kustomization inside a folder in a git repo.

#### Problem

I extracted the deployment and service manifests but they have (alot of) autogenerated fields. I don't know how to make a minimal yaml out of each manifest.

#### What I Tried So Far

1. Extracting my app's deployment and service yamls from my production k8s to a folder (with the autogenerated fields).
2. Created a kustomization.yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ./service.yaml
  - ./deployment.yaml
```

3. I setup a dev k8s locally on my map with k3d.

#### Questions

1. I don't know what I should do to make a minimal folder with: deployment.yaml, service.yaml and kustomization.yaml.
2. I'm not even sure this is what I should do to make a minimal example of kustomization.
3. How can I test my self?

Comment: For cleaning YAML from runtime version: there's no standard way of doing it.  You have to get to know the YAML, memorize the default values, and figure out what you want to get new default and what defaults you should "bake into" each deployment (in case you or admin change defaults in future versions).

Comment: That does looks like a good minimal start, but just 1 guy's opinion.